# Want value from multiple same name class/id sub tag all in js

Tags: javascript

I have 3 class call items. In each class there are 3 tags: `span`, `input` and `p`.

I want to get `input` tag value with `span` and `p` tag value from each class through JavaScript.

```
<p id="item">
<input type="text" value="0" class="qty">
<span class="name">Pepsi</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to put a unique `id` to each element and then use the `getElementById` JavaScript function with the appropriate property.

For example, to get the value of the `p` element (since it has an id already) you can use:

```
var text = document.getElementById('item').innerHTML;
```

If you don't want to give ids to the rest of the elements, you can iterate them as follows:

```
var myList = document.getElementById('item');
for(i = j = 0; i < myList .childNodes.length; i++) { //code goes here }
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, i know.. But what if i dont know how many elements.. Means my block of item is not static..  Thanx for your response..

Comment: You can then maybe try to use jQuery and select all items from a given class? It's not exactly clear to me what you are trying to achieve.